# vim / file explorer: make browsing directory the current directory

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm starting to use vim's native explorer (`:E`). *My doubt*: when I press `c` to "make browsing directory the current directory" nothing happens.. When I used nerdTree and did the same operation (`:NERDTreeCWD`), that directory was placed at the top of the exporer and the directories upper were "hidden".

It just seems pressing `c` is not doing anything..

NOTE: Im using the tree view on explorer, instead of the default one. I pressed `i` to change the view.

Im using 7.4.52

Comment: You can use `:pwd` to check if the current directory changed after pressing `c`.

Comment: @Marth no, `:pwd` outputs always `/home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *netrw* command works different than *NERDTree*'s. It doesn't apply to the directory under the cursor, but to the one currently being browsed. So if you want to make a subdir the current one, first go into it (via `<Enter>`), then press `c`.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Ingo's answer. If you always want netrw to make the current browsing directory the current vim directory, you can set the option `let g:netrw_keepdir=0` in your `.vimrc`.

This allows you to use netrw to browse directories and use vim to operate in that directory. For example, you can use vim's command `:e <filename>` to create a new file instead of netrw's command `% <filename>`.

To learn more about netrw I recommend reading the help pages `:help netrw-quickhelp`